# External Javascript is not being imported properly in HTML, using Flask, Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, jinja2

I'm developing a web app using Flask and nGinx. I am importing some Javascript modules in my main template, but it seems that this code is not being executed at all.

This is my code:

**base.html** (only the important part)

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} Some Title</title>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/debug.js') }}"></script>-->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/model.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/control.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/cmdmenu.js') }}"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='flot/jquery.flot.js') }}"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js') }}"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test-div.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/final.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/menu.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/tipsy.css') }}">
</head>
```

**debug.js**

```
window.alert('hola');
```

**model.js**

```
window.alert('holbbbba');
```

**control.js**

```
var namespace = '/test'; 
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
});
window.alert('pre');
// moooooooore and moore code here
```

The problem is, that the `debug.js` alert appears but `model.js` and `control.js` alerts won't. The strangest thing is that the socket connection is being done correctly. I have tried putting some `console.log` inside these files but nothing happen at the browser console. Obviously, the original `js` files were larger before, but trying to minimize them, even making them equal (model and debug, for instance) does not seem to give me any insights. Besides, I have checked and rechecked the syntax, and everything seems ok.

The filenames are ok, as they are in the `/static` directory of my project and using the `url_for` jinja/flask's function. I really don't know what exactly is going on with this. I would be glad if you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the files have syntax errors. There's nothing about that in the Javascript console? What browser are you using to debug this?

Comment: In the developers console, in the network tab are the files loading? Are there any errors in the console?